# OpenGL ES 2.0 on Android - Ortographic and setLookAt matrix together

Tags: android, matrix, opengl-es

I'm trying to draw a simple triangle on the screen combining and ortographic projection and a "Matrix.setLookAtM" projection, but It's not rendering it.

I tried so many combinations and thought on what could be wrong but didn't solve the issue.

The ortographic matrix is fine (I can render the triangle with only this matrix) and the matrix multiplication syntax I assume is also fine (If I set "a_Vision" to be the identity matrix the triangle is also rendered).

I think them I'm missing any conceptual idea.

Also, I should multiply "a_Vision" x "a_OrtographicProjection" or "a_OrtographicProjection" x "a_Vision"?

The code is below.

```
package com.opengl01_themostbasic;

import static android.opengl.GLES20.GL_FLOAT;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glDrawArrays;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glUniform4f;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;
import android.opengl.Matrix;


public class RendererClass implements Renderer {

int shaderProgram;

int variableToSayWhereTheVertexShaderShouldFindInformation;
int variableToSayWhereTheFragmentShaderShouldFindInformation;
int variableToSayWhereTheMatrixShouldFindInformation;

int BYTES_PER_FLOAT = 4;
FloatBuffer vertexData;

float[] a_OrtographicProjection = new float[16];
float[] a_Vision = new float[16];
float[] a_sTemp = new float[16];
float[] a_Result = new float[16];

public RendererClass(Context context){

    float[] myVertices = {

            // X, Y, Z

            -8f,  8f, -2f,
             0f, -4f, -2f,
             5f,  3f, -2f

    };

    ByteBuffer intermediateBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(myVertices.length*BYTES_PER_FLOAT);
    intermediateBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

    vertexData = intermediateBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexData.put(myVertices);

}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 arg0, EGLConfig config) {

    GLES20.glClearColor(0.4f, 0.5f, 0.8f, 1.0f);


    String vertexShaderCode =   "attribute vec4 myVertexPositionInsideOpenGL;"
                              + "uniform mat4 a_Result;"

                              + "void main(){" 
                              +     "gl_Position = a_Result*myVertexPositionInsideOpenGL;"
                              + "}";


    String fragmentShaderCode = "precision mediump float;" 
                              + "uniform vec4 myColorsInsideOpenGL;" 

                              + "void main(){" 
                              +     "gl_FragColor = myColorsInsideOpenGL;"
                              + "}";

    int vertexShaderID = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    int fragmentShaderID = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    GLES20.glShaderSource(vertexShaderID, vertexShaderCode);
    GLES20.glShaderSource(fragmentShaderID, fragmentShaderCode);

    GLES20.glCompileShader(vertexShaderID);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(fragmentShaderID);

    shaderProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

    GLES20.glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShaderID);
    GLES20.glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShaderID);

    GLES20.glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);    
    GLES20.glUseProgram(shaderProgram); 

    variableToSayWhereTheVertexShaderShouldFindInformation = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "myVertexPositionInsideOpenGL");
    variableToSayWhereTheFragmentShaderShouldFindInformation = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "myColorsInsideOpenGL");
    variableToSayWhereTheMatrixShouldFindInformation = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "a_Result");

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(variableToSayWhereTheVertexShaderShouldFindInformation);

    vertexData.position(0);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(variableToSayWhereTheVertexShaderShouldFindInformation, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, vertexData);

}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 arg0, int width, int height) {

    Matrix.orthoM(a_OrtographicProjection, 0, -20, 20, -20, 20, 2, -4);
    Matrix.setLookAtM(a_Vision, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    Matrix.multiplyMM(a_sTemp, 0, a_Vision, 0, a_OrtographicProjection, 0);
    System.arraycopy(a_sTemp, 0, a_Result, 0, a_sTemp.length);

}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) {

    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);     

    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(variableToSayWhereTheMatrixShouldFindInformation, 1, false, a_Result, 0);

    glUniform4f(variableToSayWhereTheFragmentShaderShouldFindInformation, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);   

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tentatively, try:

```
Matrix.setLookAtM(a_Vision, 0, 0, 0, 3.0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
```

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/Matrix.html#setLookAtM%28float%5B%5D,%20int,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29),

> [...] an eye point, a center of view, and an up vector

and you're just defining an eye point (0,0,3), a center of view (0,0,0) but no up vector.

Comment: It was "tentatively" :)